# How can I format time to a dayjs object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dayjs

I have the following code

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

const abc = dayjs("09:00:00")
console.log(abc)
```

abc in console is

[image: an invalid date]

how can I make this into a valid date, the condition being the input is always going to be in format "09:00:00"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To get this to work, you'll need to enable the [CustomParseFormat](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/custom-parse-format) plugin. Then you can specify a format string for dayjs to use. For example:

```js
const abc = dayjs("09:00:00", "HH:mm:ss");
console.log(abc);
```

Will result in the following:

[image: The result of abc]

You can read about the different options for the format string at the dayjs documentation: https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format

Answer (score 16):

If you installed dayjs using npm, you can use CustomParseFormat plugin like this.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import customParseFormat from "dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat";

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
const day = dayjs("09:00:00", "HH:mm:ss");
console.log(day);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 16+

import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';

const dayjsObjectTime = dayjs('09:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');

Also **dayjs** has a method **.toDate()** if you want to get a Date format object from a **dayjs** object.

const dateObject = dayjs('09:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss').toDate()